# How do I use cURLpp with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, curlpp

I'm using VS 2019, have downloaded all the cURLpp headers, put them and the cURL headers in an include folder and added this include directory under Project Properties -> Additional Include Directories. When I try to build example00.cpp from the cURLpp site, I get errors saying I have an unresolved external symbol. I've never used a third party library with C++ before, so please explain like I'm an idiot. Should I have a dll or lib file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: ***Should I have a dll or lib file?*** yes.

Comment: @drescherjm I downloaded the cURLpp source code and there was no dll or lib file - is this something I can generate myself from the source code?

Comment: It's built using CMake. That is what the CMakeLists.txt file is in the `curlpp-0.8.1` folder of the download.

Comment: @drescherjm is there a reason the dll file isn't just made available?

Comment: Probably because the source code is for multiple compilers and operating systems. Many open source projects use CMake these days.

Comment: @drescherjm I've run cMake with cURL, but when trying to run with cURLpp it says it isn't installed

Comment: I assume it said that it can't find curl when you tried to configure.

Comment: You may want to investigate using vcpkg. https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg both curl and curlpp are in vcpkg and will be automatically downloaded and compiled with a few simple commands after you get vcpkg installed.

Comment: See here to see the list of packages that vcpkg can build for your compiler. https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports

Comment: @drescherjm thanks, I'll check that out!

Answer (score 2):

I use vcpkg to install `curlpp`, and I find that my project configuration in visual studio is `x64`, if I use `x86 curlpp` it will get build error, I need to use `x64 curlpp` then build sucess.

This is the include step:

1. Run cmd command: `vcpkg install curlpp:x64-windows`
2. goto Project > Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories, add `yourVcpkgFolderPath\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\`
3. goto Project > Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies, add `curlpp.lib`

Then build the project, it should build success.