# Installing curlpp library

Tags: c++, curlpp

I need your help in installing the curlpp library. I'm still a newbie to C++ and haven't installed any external libraries yet, I browsed around for quite some time but could only find installation wizards or compilers or automated processes. I want to know how to do it manually. Like fully, you go in File Explorer and put all the source code in by yourself. I want to code specifically in Visual Studio Code.

Thanks for you help!!

Comment: There's no uniform way of distributing C++ libraries.  Check the library's documentation for instructions on how to build it, including any needed dependencies.

Comment: The instructions are at the beginning of this pdf: [https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp/blob/master/doc/guide.pdf](https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp/blob/master/doc/guide.pdf) with this said these are for linux, macOS .. if you are on windows and using msvc you may want to use vcpkg. This probably requires you spend a few hours time to understand what you are doing being a newbie.

Comment: Here is a linked question for using curlpp with Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583817/how-do-i-use-curlpp-with-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583817/how-do-i-use-curlpp-with-visual-studio)